# WPF Command usage beyond MVVM

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, command

I've been trying to learn proper MVVM usage with WPF. I mostly get it, but I'm a little stuck on a specific issue with using commands. I get that a command allows me to perform the same action that can be triggered by multiple UI elements, but all examples I've seen of this have the command defined in the view model or the view.

How do you use commands when the scope of action goes further than the view model? For example, maybe I want to define a command for closing the application. This will allow a button and a menu item to both trigger closing, but what if closing the application also requires other actions, such as closing a database connection and writing a file? These types of tasks usually happen somewhere besides in the model or view.

In this scenario, Do I just wire the UI elements to an event instead? Do I declare an event in the viewmodel and have the command trigger the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been trying to learn proper MVVM usage with WPF.

In practice, MVVM can be summed up in one sentence: *The view model is responsible for providing all of the data and the functionality that is required by its view*.

> How do you use commands when the scope of action goes further than the view model?

In MVVM, each view has a view model, so there is no *further than the view model*. A great way to handle the use of `ICommand`s in WPF is to utilise one of the `delegate`-based `Command`s available, such as the popular `RelayCommand`. You can find details for that in the [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) page on MSDN.

In the UI, they're used just like any other `ICommand`, but in the view model, you can just use methods or even inline `delegate`s to handle the `ICommand.Execute` and `ICommand.CanExecute` methods. I use my own version of the `RelayCommand` and for your scenario, I'd do something like this:

```
public ICommand CloseCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new ActionCommand(action => Close(null), canExecute => CanClose(null));
    }
}

private void Close(object commandParameter)
{
    if (SomeDataItem.HasChanges)
    {
        if (WindowManager.AskUserIfTheyWantToSave(SomeDataItem)) 
            DataProvider.Save(SomeDataItem);
    }
    HardDriveManager.SaveSettings();
    WindowManager.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

Now obviously, you don't have my `...Manager` classes, but it doesn't matter *how* you save this and that... this just shows you what is possible.

> what if closing the application also requires other actions, such as closing a database connection?

Modern database technologies don't really require you to manually close a database connection at any point.

At this point, I'd like to make it clear that when using MVVM, it is *perfectly* acceptable to handle events in the code behind of `UserControl`s, or even the `MainWindow`. So there is absolutely no problem with saving settings in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` like this:

```
Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
```

...

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Reload();
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    Left = Settings.Default.ApplicationLocation.X;
    Top = Settings.Default.ApplicationLocation.Y;
    Width = Settings.Default.ApplicationSize.Width;
    Height = Settings.Default.ApplicationSize.Height;
    WindowState = Settings.Default.IsApplicationMaximised ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;
}

private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.ApplicationLocation = new Point(Left, Top);
    Settings.Default.ApplicationSize = new Size(Width, Height);
    Settings.Default.IsApplicationMaximised = WindowState == WindowState.Maximized;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

> Do I declare an event in the viewmodel and have the command trigger the event?

Events are UI objects and should never be seen in a view model... we don't want any UI related dlls in the view model project references. When you really need to handle an event, you can just handle it in the code behind and remember that you can access the data bound view model from the view code behind like this:

```
SomeViewModel viewModel = (SomeViewModel)DataContext;
```

Or perhaps better, is to handle the event in an Attached Property that you can simply attach in XAML. Rather than extending this rather long answer explaining how to do that, I advise you to search online, as there are plenty of examples. Oh actually, I just remembered that I explained how to do this to someone in the [What's the best way to pass event to ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285577/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-event-to-viewmodel/21285863#21285863) post here on Stack Overflow.

So this went on longer than I had intended, but hopefully it answered (some of) your questions.

Comment: Thanks for all of that and pardon my multi-question post. Just for clarity, my database connection comment was just something random I came up with for something that a view and a model wouldn't directly control. Also, I'm saddened by the broken source code link in the MSDN link you posted, but it still had some good info.
Regarding your example where you define CloseCommand and Close(), is that something that you define in the view model, or would that be something defined in a manager class somewhere and injected into a view model?

Comment: Yeah, the `Command`s are always in the view model... hopefully, you'll see how much easier it is using these `delegate`-based `Command`s too. I also find that it's much better keeping all of the functionality logic in the view models, where it belongs, rather than in a bunch of separate `RoutedCommand` implementations.

Comment: Just for future visitors, here's a post that really helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3540895/764371. There are clearly differing opinions, but I think the question managed to ask what I was trying to wrap my head around a bit more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I just wire the UI elements to an event instead?

**NO.**

If your commands need to perform whatever actions, just call these actions in the `Execute()` method.

How you perform the interaction between the ViewModel and the rest of your application (Data Access layer, business logic, services) is completely up to you.