# Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm using `<i:EventTrigger>` to play a storyboard animation that changes the foreground of a label. (I need to use this type of trigger because I'm using its SourceObject property in order to bind to the datacontext's event. I removed the binding from the example for simplicity).
When this animation ends, I want to change the label back to its original color (blue), but not in the code-behind because I'm using MVVM. (I'm familiar with the Completed event of the storyborad, but I can't use it because it demends code behind and breaks the MVVM pattern.)

This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MySB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                            From="0.0" To="0.6" Duration="0:0:0.6" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3"
                            AutoReverse="True" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GradientStop3"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset"
                            From="0.4" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.6" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3"
                            AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label x:Name="CollectionTabHeader" Foreground="Blue" Height="30" Width="80">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop1" Color="Red" Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop2" Color="White" Offset="0.2" />
                                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop3" Color="White" Offset="0.3" />
                                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop4" Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource MySB}"     
                                    ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        MyLabel
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is nothing wrong with using the code behind to handle events when using MVVM. Secondly, even if you *really* don't want to use the code behind in these situations, then you can handle that event in an MVVM-friendly manner by implementing an Attached Property.

Rather than explaining the whole situation again in this question, I'd prefer to recommend that you read through my answer to the [What's the best way to pass event to ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285577/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-event-to-viewmodel/21285863#21285863) question here on Stack Overflow. It contains a full code example and although it deals with a different event, that makes little difference... just replace the `GetPreviewKeyDown` event with your `Completed` event instead.

Comment: thanks, but would you happen to know if this can be handled by xaml only?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it can't... it's not a `RoutedEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating code behind with MVVM pattern is not an end in itself - it's just side effect (good one although). Purpose of Model-View-ViewModel is: eliminate mixing of application logic and view code - so application could be testable (and code a bit more reusable). There is nothing wrong about code-behind view-related code which doesn't affect application logic / data manipulation.