# How to differ click input between inside and outside of a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, inputbinding

(Please take each of controls stated below as control created using MVVM pattern)

So, I have a `UserControl` which I place on my `MainWindow`. I want my `UserControl`, if clicked (in the `MainWindow`, inside the `UserControl`), the background changed into another color, and if I click in the `MainWindow`, but outside of `UserControl`, then the `UserControl`'s background will change to the original color.

What I've tried :

1. I've tried to apply a Command inside the `UserControl.InputBindings` which to detect Mouse Input (`MouseBinding`), but the only `MouseBinding` raised is the `MouseBinding` in the `Window.InputBindings` (which should be raised **ONLY** when the click input is outside the `UserControl`), but apparently, wherever a click happen, the only `MouseBinding` raised is only the one in `Window.InputBindings`.
2. Differ the `CommandParameter` between `MouseBinding` in `Window.InputBindings` and `UserControl.InputBindings`.

Question :

1. How to differ the `MouseBinding` between clicking inside the `UserControl` and outside?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"/>` ? Can you add more detail... what does the UserControl do?  It seems to me that the most common scenario is that people want to show visual indications whether a certain element has focus.. is this your case?

Comment: Yes. exactly. But I also want to access its "focused" boolean value (Something like `if(focused){//do something}`

Comment: what `something`? that something can also be achieved with triggers probably...

Comment: i mean in `UserControl`'s ICommand's `CanExecute` returning the "focus boolean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just attach a `PreviewMouseDown` event handler to both the `Window` *and* the `UserControl` and handle both events *in the `Window`*:

```
<Window ... PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown">
    <UserControl Name="Control" PreviewMouseDown="UserControl_PreviewMouseDown" ... / >
</Window>
```

...

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Control.Background = someNewColourBrush;
}


private void UserControl_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Control.Background = originalColourBrush;
}
```

Comment: Ha... yeah, I normally go for the simplest solution these days, not the best. I've often found that when I roll out the big guns and suggest a great solution, I just end up having to answer a million comments asking further questions and I just don't have the time (or patience) to do that anymore.

Comment: This is correct, but I am trying to do "the right MVVM" way.

Comment: @MosesAprico to clarify, this solution does not "break" MVVM, because it uses code behind for UI-specific purposes, which is OK.

Comment: I'd agree with @HighCore here. This is purely UI related and so not needed in the view model. However, when you *do* need to handle an event in the view model, you can wrap it up in an Attached Property. See my answer to the [What's the best way to pass event to ViewModel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285577/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-event-to-viewmodel/21285863#21285863) question to see how it's done.