# How to get Selected Node in TreeView without Code Behind using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I want to Bind to ViewModel the selected Node of the Treeview , notice that every node is a NavPoint (from the EPUB's Table Of Content) , How create a dependency property "SelectedNode" on  Control that Binds the Selected Node in the correct Type .
I used

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem ,ElementName=myTreeview}"/>
```

but i want to bind it to my MainWindowViewModel.cs class to manipulate it and make some changes over it !

Comment: Use behaviour OR extend TreeView like provided in answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the [`TreeView.SelectedItemChanged` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), then you could update your `SelectedNode` property:

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    YourSelectedNodeProperty = (TreeViewItem)e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is using MVVM pattern. this works but I hope someone can shed light on how to do this using MVVM

Comment: @Rob, to use this method with MVVM, simply wrap this event in an Attached Property. I have documented an example of this in my answer to the [What's the best way to pass event to ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285577/whats-the-best-way-to-pass-event-to-viewmodel/21285863#21285863) question, here on Stack Overflow.